# Vaadin TabSheet. Additional functionality in Tab captions

Tags: java, vaadin7

I m a newbie in Vaadin and I am using a TabSheet where I attach some tabs. I was wondering if I could get some more functionality from their captions. 
For instance, when a tab is selected and the user clicks its caption then a dropdown menu can appear.
I have already experimented with the existing listeners of TabSheet and I concluded that I have to make a custom listener. The thing is that I cannot find a way to fire the event when I click on the selected tab caption...

Answer (score 2):

You could use SelectedTabChangeListener on a TabSheet. It would fire the event when the caption is clicked, and you could reselect your current tab, etc.. It would be cumbersome.

Why not use the MenuBar? Isn't it exactly what you want? https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!menubars

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was looking for something totally different. I will use though your idea  menu bars on something else!

Comment: From [the docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-tabsheet.html#layout.tabsheet.events): *Reselecting the currently selected tab does not fire the event*. That could be a problem if he would like to show the dropdown menu in the current active tab. In fact, this is the case for me and it prevents me from using SelectedTabChangeListener for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (Vaadin 7.4), what you can do is you can surround the tab caption with a `<div onclick="...">captionText</div>` and add a JavaScript callback function:

```
final TabSheet sheet = new TabSheet();
sheet.setTabCaptionsAsHtml(true); // don't forget this!

// This is the callback
JavaScript.getCurrent().addFunction("clickedTab", new JavaScriptFunction() {
    @Override
    public void call(JsonArray arguments) {
        LOGGER.info(arguments.getString(0)); // this is 'some identifier'                   
    }
});

final TabSheet.Tab tab = sheet.addTab(component, "<div onclick=\"clickedTab('some identifier');\">captionText/div>");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik! I will give it a try in a new project!